# Finding a variable text in another textfile and get the containing line

Tags: windows, powershell, text

quite new to powershell, i'm struggling with the following problem and im not finding any good answer in the interwebs.

I have a textfile "ID.txt" containing lines with IDs in form of "SBS1234568" in variable length.

I have another textfile "IPs.txt" containing lines with IP adresses and the mentioned ID above separated by ";" aka "10.55.0.0/24 ; SBS1234568"

I now want to find IDs listet in "id.txt" in "IPs.txt" and get the entire line from "IPs.txt" to output it to another file.

I tried with a foreach and IF but I was not able to get it anywhere near...
EDIT:
This is what I tried:

```
$IPs = Get-Content IPs.txt 
$ID = Get-Content ID.txt
Foreach ($line in $ID) {
   IF (Select-String $IPs -Pattern "$line") {
   Continue;
   }
$new_ip = $line | out-file -FilePath new_ips.txt;
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

regards
blitzdesigner

PS: there is a crosspost at powershell.org: https://powershell.org/forums/topic/finding-a-variable-text-in-another-textfile-and-get-the-containing-line/

**EDIT**
So I got a working solution which will also handle IPv6-Adresses:

Input-File for IDs.txt:

```
SBL341597
SBL341397
SBL341697
```

Input-File for IPs.txt:

```
210.57.128.0/18 ; SBL233459
210.57.192.0/20 ; SBL237213
212.95.144.0/22 ; SBL198435
213.130.88.0/22 ; SBL391310
213.176.20.0/22 ; SBL341697
217.8.116.0/22 ; SBL482777
217.8.117.0/24 ; SBL485640
2a07:6800::/29 ; SBL341597
2a09:ac80::/29 ; SBL494347
```

This is then the code:

```
ForEach ($ID in $(Get-Content IDs.txt))
{
    Try
    {
        ((Select-String IPs.txt -Pattern "$ID")) | 
                Out-File -FilePath new_ips_to_set.txt -Append
    }
    Catch{}
}

#clean up output
$new_ips_input = Get-Content new_ips_to_set.txt
$regexname = "(?:.*?\:){2}(.*)\s*"
$new_rules = $new_ips_input | select-string $regexname -AllMatches |
 ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
```

Comment: "I tried with ..." - please show the attempted code, someone might be able to help you salvage it :)

Comment: You should be able to do it the same way as when using `cmd.exe` instead of `powershell.exe`, i.e. `findstr.exe /IG:".\ID.txt" ".\IPs.txt" > ".\new_ips.txt"`. In this example I've used `.` to signify that my text files are located in the current directory, feel free to adjust those if your files are elsewhere.

Comment: thank you for the idea for cmd, but I'd like to stay in powershell, as this is just part of a bigger script which already got a lot of work into it :-)

Comment: I didn't say it was for `cmd.exe` @blitzdesigner, I told you that you can use that same method in `powershell.exe`. Just type it, _(or copy and paste it)_, into a Windows PowerShell prompt window, and it will work exaclty as I have explained and shown!

Comment: sorry, I got it wrong. your right :-)
I tried it, but unfortunately, it will output the full IPs.txt to new_ips.txt, no matter whats in ID.txt. Isnt it important, that I just have part of the string in ID.txt?

Comment: The command I gave you, @blitzdesigner, uses each line of `ID.txt`, and outputs each line of `IPs.txt`, which contains that case insensitive string to a file named `new-ips.txt`, which is exactly what my reading of your question was. If I was mistaken, then please explain what you want which is different.

Comment: See [Example 2: Find matches in text files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7) from the Powershell Help Files.

Comment: @Compo your solution totally works, but interestingly only on my Windows 10 machine. If I run it on Windows server 2019, it just outputs the full IPs like I said before. 
As I got a working solution from postanote, I will not start digging into why findstr.exe does differently on W Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really show what these files look like, just a sample string from them. Do they have headers? are they just a sinlge column list? Are they quoated like you have here?

So, me making assumptions:

```
Clear-Host
'
SBS1234568
SBS1234569
' | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\IDs.txt'

"
'10.55.0.0/24 ; SBS1234568' 
'10.55.0.0/24 ; SBS1234570' 
" | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\IPs.txt'


ForEach ($ID in $(Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\IDs.txt'))
{
    Try
    {
        ((Select-String -Path 'D:\Temp\IPs.txt' -Pattern "$ID") -split(':'))[3] | 
        Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\Validate_ID_IP_List.txt' -Append
    }
    Catch{}
}
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\Validate_ID_IP_List.txt' 
# Results
<#
'10.55.0.0/24 ; SBS1234568' 
#>
```

***Update as per our last exchange***

Other examples:

```
# One
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\IDs.txt' | 
ForEach {
    Try
    {
        Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\IPs.txt' | 
        Select-String -Pattern $PSItem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
        Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\Validate_ID_IP_List.txt' -Append
    }
    Catch{}
}
# Results
<#
'10.55.0.0/24 ; SBS1234568' 
#>


# Two  
$IDData = '
SBL233459
SBL198435
SBL341697
' | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header ID 

$IPData = '
210.57.128.0/18 ; SBL233459
210.57.192.0/20 ; SBL237213
212.95.144.0/22 ; SBL198435
213.130.88.0/22 ; SBL391310
213.176.20.0/22 ; SBL341697
217.8.116.0/22 ; SBL482777
217.8.117.0/24 ; SBL485640
2a07:6800::/29 ; SBL341597
2a09:ac80::/29 ; SBL494347
' | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Header IP, ID

$IDData.ID | 
ForEach {
    $IP = $IPData -match $PSItem
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        IP = $IP.IP
        ID = $IP.ID
    } | 
    Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\Validate_ID_IP_List.txt' -Append
}
# Results
<#
IP               ID       
--               --       
210.57.128.0/18  SBL233459
212.95.144.0/22  SBL198435
213.176.20.0/22  SBL341697
#>

# Three
$IDData = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\IDs.txt'
# Results
<#
SBS1234568
SBS1234569
#>
$IPData = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\IPs.txt'
# Results
<#
'10.55.0.0/24 ; SBS1234568' 
'10.55.0.0/24 ; SBS1234570'
#>

# Four
Clear-Host
$IDData | 
ForEach {
    Try
    {
        $IPData | Select-String $PSItem | 
        Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\Validate_ID_IP_List.txt' -Append
    }
    Catch{}
}
# Results
<#
'10.55.0.0/24 ; SBS1234568'
#>
```

Comment: This is working fine, sorry for not providing more detailed information. The lines are not quoted. The thing is, I tried to change your solution to work w/o using files and just using variables: `ForEach ($ID in $new_ids)
{
    Try
    {
        ((Select-String -InputObject $IPs -Pattern "$ID") -split(':'))[3] | 
                Out-File -FilePath new_ips_to_set.txt -Append
    }
    Catch{}
}` but this is not outputting anything.

Comment: True, I wrote about text files. I thought it does not really matter if I handle a file or directly a variable, which is obviously not the case :-). I get the the content out of another operation and wanted to spare me the creation of a temporary file and handle everything in memory. I already learned that there are million ways to achieve the same thing in PowerShell. Thank you for your help, I will try to figure out how to do it w/o a temp file for better understanding. If I fail, I will gladly come back to you :-)

Comment: No worries, take I'll attach a few others for you to toy with and yep, it does nto matter whetehr you use text or stream in it live no real need for text files if they can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select-String` on the IPs.txt file but one important thing you're missing is your text in ID.txt is in this format

```
"SBS1234568"
```

Therefore when you're trying to match a line in IPs.txt, it is effectively this

```
"10.55.0.0/24 ; SBS1234568" -match "SBS1234568"  # this is $false
```

You'd have to remove at least the first quote, but instead of doing all that I would treat it as a CSV.

```
$idfile    = New-TemporaryFile
$ipfile    = New-TemporaryFile
$newipfile = 'c:\temp\new_ips.txt'

@'
"SBS1234568"
"SBS345689123"
"SBS87654"
"SBS87612354"
'@ | Set-Content $idfile -Encoding utf8

@'
"10.55.0.0/24 ; SBS1234568"
"10.44.0.0/24 ; SBS345689123"
"10.33.0.0/24 ; SBS87654"
"10.22.0.0/24 ; SBS87612354"
"10.1.0.0/24 ; SB612354"
'@ | Set-Content $ipfile -Encoding utf8

Import-Csv $idfile -Header id | foreach {
    (Select-String $ipfile -Pattern $_.id).line
} | Set-Content $newipfile -Encoding utf8

Get-Content $newipfile
```

Output

```
"10.55.0.0/24 ; SBS1234568"
"10.44.0.0/24 ; SBS345689123"
"10.33.0.0/24 ; SBS87654"
"10.22.0.0/24 ; SBS87612354"
```

I added an extra entry in $ipfile to demonstrate it excluding the non-matching line

Comment: The lines are not quoted, sorry if this was not precisely described. This could make things easier I think.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The posted solution works whether they are quoted or not and is demonstrated with files.